# Current working directory shows differently in python after refresh the page

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

This is really weird situation.
I'm trying to create an web framework using Python from scratch.
And I'm trying to get the current working directory (technically the full path of the current .py file) of a file using below code.

```
os.getcwd()
```

The problem is..
If I type above code and restart uwsgi server then print it.
At the first time, it always prints like below.

```
/var/www/html/mydocroot
```

Then if I refresh the page, 'mydocroot' directory disappears automatically like below.

```
/var/www/html
```

And it creates same output after refreshing the page as above.
I spent almost whole day to figure out that issue.
Any idea or same experiences?

and also I tried,

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

this one as well.

For example,

```
/var/www/html/mydocroot/Core/Settings
```

is the result when I restart uwsgi server,

```
/var/www/html/Core/Settings
```

When I refresh the page, 'mydocroot' disappears by itself as above.

```html
server{
        server_name example.com;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://www.example.com permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/var/www/html/example/myapp.sock;
    }
}
```

Above is my nginx server config. and below is wsgi configuration.

```html
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 1
touch-reload = /var/www/html/ggr/wsgi.py
socket = myapp.sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
max-requests = 1
die-on-term = true
logger = file:/var/log/ggr.log
catch-exceptions = true
```

Comment: what web server and wsgi server are you using?

Comment: I'm using under nginx server on ubuntu. I have 16 years experience as a PHP developer. But in this case.., it's pretty weird. The result should be the same all the time as you mentioned before..

Comment: May want to include your nginx config and wsgi file

Comment: I added NGix and WSGI file into my original post. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Files don't have a "current working directory".  There's just one global current working directory for a given process.  The current working directory can change

```
os.chdir('/new/working/directory')
```

If you want the directory of a specific file, you can do this

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: Yes, but it should print the **same thing every time**, it shouldn't change on subsequent calls.

Comment: It's pretty weird isn't it? I turned off viltualenv for testing cuz I thought it might be the problem. and also changed folder permission as well. but still no luck on that